# Bidirectional cascade on self referenced join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a table which has a self reference join table to itself.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EmployeeDependency> employeeDependencies;
}

@Entity
public class EmployeeDependency {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Employee employeeDependency;
}
```

As we can see the relation is managed by `mappedBy = "employee"`.
DB looks like this for the dependency table

```
EmployeeDependency
----------------------------------------
id employee_id employee_dependency_id
----------------------------------------
1     2         3
2     2         4
3     3         10
```

Now when I try deleting `employee= 2` , it is deleting the references in `EmployeeDependency` table and also deleting the record from `Employee` table as dependency is managed by `employee` in the mapping `mappedBy = "employee"`. This is expected and working as it is written.

But now when I try to delete `employee = 10` which is in other side of relation, I was getting `foreign key` reference error.

I was able to delete it if I put a dummy reference in `Employee` entity like this

```
   @Entity
   public class Employee {
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<EmployeeDependency> employeeDependencies;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeDependency", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<EmployeeDependency> dummyEmployeeDependencies;
    }
```

But this doesn't seems to be right! how can I put a bidirectional cascade so I can delete ids from either side of relation

Comment: Why wouldn't it be right? If you want to delete all the EmployeeDependency that reference the employee being deleted using any of the many to one associations, this is what you need to do (or you need to find them yourself and delete them first). I'm not sure what you mean by "so I can delete ids from either side of relation": you always delete from the same side: employee. But you have two separate associations between dependency and employee.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be right? I didn't like to have this `dummyEmployeeDependencies` for only cascade purpose and this doesn't look good in code. I am looking for way to map both dependency and employee with a single mapped by that can remove both sides but I could be completely dump thinking that. Just not sure if having two statements like these are right for coding standards. I understand your point as well

Comment: mappedBy has absolutely nothing to do with cascading deletes. Let's take an understandable example: an employee has professional contacts, and personal contacts. But in your model, you only have the list of personal contacts in the Employee class. And you're telling JPA to delete the personal contacts whenever an employee is being deleted. Why would the professional contacts be deleted? And if you want them deleted, then why not add them, just like the personal contacts, in the Employee entity? Or find them and delete them before deleting the employee? You need to do one of those two things.

Comment: I understand your example and but here I'm confused as Employee has a self relation. So the current configuration says 'if employee is getting deleted then remove its dependencies relation' and do not have 'if dependency is getting deleted remove its employee references'. Can you help me how to have the second case in code

Comment: *Employee has a self relation*: no, not in the code you posted. Employee has a OneToMany bidirectional association with EmployeeDependency, and EmployeeDependency has another ManyToOne unidirectional association with Employee. No sign of an association between Employee and Employee. I already told you twice how to do: make the unidirectional bidirectional with a cascade, just as the other one, or find the EmployeeDependencies to delete, and delete them before deleting the employee.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the suggestion. I will check the dependency from the code and remove the relation before actually delete it